Exact solution of non-integrable Hamiltonian system?
Following this note (Introduction to Integrability – FS 2013,
Lecturers: Dr. Marius de Leeuw, Dr. Constantin Candu), a system is said to be solved by quadratures if the solution can be constructed by
• solving a finite number of algebraic equations
• computing a finite number of integrals.
Liouville's theorem states that any integrable Hamiltonian system is solvable by quadratures.
What about the inverse of the Liouville's theorem?
Are there non-integrable Hamiltonian systems that can be solved by quadratures? Or solved exactly in some other way?

Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Depends on what you mean by "exact solution". The Kepler problem is integrable but one can't really give an "exact solution" except through an integral that can not be expressed by elementary functions. The three body problem is not integrable, but a formal solution can be given by means of a (uselessly slowly) converging infinite series if I am not mistaken.
